# XKCD Bracket Probabilities

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, rational-numbers, probability-theory

[Today's XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1529/) is a sports-tournament style bracket, where the contestants are well-known names, put into groups of possibly confusing names.

Give the probability that a given contestant will win the entire tournament, based on each contestant in a given round having an equal chance of winning that round.

#### Input

The name of a contestant.

- XKCD likes to use all upper case, but you may use whatever case makes sense for you or make your input case insensitive.
- You may assume all input names are valid.
- `Jeff Gordan` is probably a misspelling of `Jeff Gordon`.  You may choose to accept either or both of these.
- Some names include punctuation, e.g. `H. G. Wells` and `Joseph Gordon-Levitt`.  You may choose to accept names with or without punctuation (or both).  The above without punctuation would be `H G Wells` and `Joseph Gordon Levitt`
- Similarly, you may choose to accept either `Beyoncé` or `Beyonce` or both
- The `Mister/Fred Astaire/Rogers` line is a bit odd.  For this one, you must accept all of the following: `Fred Rogers`, `Mister Rogers` and `Fred Astaire`

#### Output

The probability of the given contestant winning the whole tournament, in rational form (e.g. `1/64`)

#### Examples

- Louis Armstrong will potentially play in 6 rounds, each with two contestants, so he has a 1/64 chance of winning.
- Alan Rickman will potentially play in 7 rounds, the first with 3 contestants and the rest with 2 contestants, so he has a 1/192 chance of winning.

To save you the effort of typing in all the names from the image, [explainXKCD already has them tabulated](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1529).  I've also dumped them to [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vUCXXicw).

Note the winning probabilities in the explainXKCD are wrong - they are twice as big as they should be because they are presumably forgetting the final round.  Thanks for pointing this out @Geobits.

Comment: so we have to first convert the image into text and then hardcode probability buckets .. ughh

Comment: @Optimizer [explainxkcd](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) can help you with that

Comment: @MartinBüttner That's dope

Comment: @Optimizer no image conversion required :)

Comment: You should link that in the question at the end...

Comment: @Optimizer Done.

Comment: These odds (examples and explain.xkcd) are all too high, because they're forgetting the last match (between winners of each side). Each should be halved.

Comment: @Geobits *facepalm* - let me fix that!

Comment: @sanchises Please see the second bullet point in the input spec.

Comment: explainxkcd is a wiki; why fix it with a note in the spec when you could fix it for everyone? :P

Comment: [Relevant Twitter account.](https://twitter.com/xkcdbracket).

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 161 bytes

```
1'/l_"FRE"#\_'É#)\2b626%536%"òazíF­.?§·»ùßóÿ÷ýÿÿ»×ï_ÿÿ¿ß÷ä¿ûïÿÏÅÿ¿ÿÿ~ÿþÿýó½ïÿþþ/ïþÿ®þü¾ùÿ®÷/"256b2b2*<1-,"ãÍÕý*ÔÞ)ð^sV? Ìöî²\ÅlÕáS{Á"260b5b=5,Z6t=2+1\?4?32*
```

This is a full program that expects uppercase input, with punctuation and accents exactly as shown in the pastebin.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1'%2Fl_%22FRE%22%23%5C_'%C3%89%23)%5C2b626%25536%25%22%C3%B2a%1Dz%C3%ADF%C2%AD.%3F%C2%A7%C2%B7%C2%BB%C3%B9%C3%9F%C3%B3%C3%BF%C3%B7%C3%BD%C3%BF%C3%BF%C2%BB%C3%97%C3%AF_%C3%BF%C3%BF%C2%BF%C3%9F%C3%B7%C3%A4%C2%BF%C3%BB%C3%AF%C3%BF%C3%8F%C3%85%C3%BF%C2%BF%C3%BF%C3%BF~%C3%BF%C3%BE%C3%BF%C3%BD%C3%B3%C2%BD%C3%AF%C3%BF%C3%BE%C3%BE%2F%C3%AF%C3%BE%C3%BF%C2%AE%C3%BE%C3%BC%C2%BE%C3%B9%C3%BF%C2%AE%C3%B7%2F%22256b2b2*%3C1-%2C%22%C3%A3%C3%8D%C3%95%C3%BD*%C3%94%C2%99%C3%9E)%C3%B0%5EsV%3F%09%C2%96%C3%8C%C3%B6%C3%AE%C2%B2%5C%C3%85l%C3%95%C3%A1%C2%9AS%7B%C3%81%14%22260b5b%3D5%2CZ6t%3D2%2B1%5C%3F4%3F32*&input=BEYONC%C3%89).

#### How it works

```
1'/      e# Push a 1 and a slash.
l        e# Read a line of input from STDIN.
_"FRE"#  e# Push 0 if the input starts with "FRE" and a truthy value otherwise.
\_'É#)   e# Push 1 if the input doesn't contain "É" and a falsy value otherwise.

         e# Now we hash the input:
\2b      e#     Apply base 2 conversion to turn the input into an integer.
626%536% e#     Take that integer modulo 626, then modulo 536.

"òazíF­.?§·»ùßóÿ÷ýÿÿ»×ï_ÿÿ¿ß÷ä¿ûïÿÏÅÿ¿ÿÿ~ÿþÿýó½ïÿþþ/ïþÿ®þü¾ùÿ®÷/"256b2b2*

         e# Convert the string from base 256 to base 2 and repeat it.
         e# The resulting array, [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...], contains a 0 at index X
         e# if and only if there is a possible input with hash X.

<        e# Keep the binary values before the index of the input hash.
<1-,     e# Count the number of zeroes.

"ãÍÕý*ÔÞ)ð^sV?  Ìöî²\ÅlÕáS{Á"260b5b

         e# Convert the string from base 260 to base 5.
         e# The resulting array, [2 2 2 2 2 0 4 4 0 0 ...], contains a diffrent
         e# integer for every different probability. The input with the lowest hash
         e# corresponds to the first index, the one with the highest to the last.

=        e# Retrieve the integer corresponding to the input.
5,Z6t=   e# Retrieve the corresponding element from [0 1 2 6 4].
2+       e# Add two.
1\?      e# Select the result from above or 1 for BEYONCÉ.
4?       e# Select the result from above or 4 for and FRED.
32*      e# Multiply by 32.
```

Comment: I've taken the probabilities from explainxkcd (multiplied by 2) and filled in the gaps. Hopefully, everything is correct. Fixing any probability should not  have an impact on the byte count.